# Selecting age between 6 and 18

Tags: mobile, android, checkboxes, multi-selection, ux-designer

I've got a reasonably simple requirement but can't come up with any appealing ways of presenting it to the user.

To meet the requirement, the user has to be able to choose 1 or more age groups, ranging from 6 to 18.
In its most simplest form, it would be a row or grid of 13 checkboxes with the values 6 to 18.

The selection can be completely random, i.e. 7, 10, and 18 so any kind of slider or other selector that would work with a maximum value won't work.

I'd love to hear some ideas on how to make this more appealing to the user.

Comment: You mention age group? But your examples states ages, 7,10,18 etc.
If you need to know the age of the user why not use a text box or a drop down menu with the full range?

Comment: I think the problem is the 'or more' - hence the need for 13 checkboxes.

Comment: @DanielZahra Sorry, age 'group' might not be the best description. Its simply multiple ages. It is however not free-for-all, the 6 to 18 are choices that the user is limited to, so a simple input won't be enough. I do have a full screen for this selection (together with some other simple options) so a dropdown to save space isn't needed either.

Comment: @Stefan de Bruijn is this UI for a touch interface ?

Comment: I don't get the first paragraph of your question. I don't think your question was migrated here, and if that isn't the case I don't understand why you mention stackoverflow at all. Also such comments are generally considered useless noise in a question text. Avoid them. If you have to add that as a comment to the question itself.

Comment: @bbh Yeah, mobile and tablet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work:

Since you have such a small number of options just make them large, press-able buttons which display a checkmark once you tap them.

This list obviously scrolls off the screen but I think you get the idea.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJeqqC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I'll accept this answer just to end the thread. I'd probably have gone with something like this. Fortunately, I could circumvent the whole situation by reshaping the data, completely skipping this awkward question.

Answer (score 14):

**One idea: draggable multiple range sliders**

Instead of 13 checkboxes you could use one slider, on which the user can select multiple ranges and single values.

See an example of such a slider here: http://blog.153.io/Elessar/.
Your slider would then go from 6 to 18 and instead of having time labels you could show the selected age. When moving the spans you have to update the label.

[image]

Comment: That's quite a cool widget! I'd have to make one on Android myself, but nice suggestion!

Comment: Nice answer. I played with that control for a while but after adding a bunch of items I couldn't work out how to remove one. From some GitHub comments I noticed it's possibly by double-clicking middle-mouse-button but this didn't work for me.

Comment: A requirement like that will never have a simple control, so this feels as intuitive as possible. If you have to create a new one yourself I'd divide the slider into equal boxes (kinda like @bluntfakie's answer). This way you are sure about which ages you selected.

Comment: I did not enjoy using that slider. It would likely infuriate me on a mobile device.

Comment: OTOH I liked it quite a bit (on OS X with a touchpad). There is room for improvement, of course. I couldn't figure out how to remove a slider, either; the sliders don't combine when adjacent (which you'd want for age ranges but not for e.g., appointments); and it doesn't support zoomin/zoomout gestures (which I expected to increase or decrease the range of the selected slider). But as an interface it's quite nice.

Answer (score 5):

**Painting a row of numbers**

Imagine you have a row of numbers in boxes, you can click individual boxes to select/deselect them, or you can click and drag to select multiple ages.

```
Click to select ages (click and drag to select multiple ages)
          | 6| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|
```

Comment: I don't see how this is better than having a row of checkboxes, apart from saving minimal space by deleting the box

Comment: The benefit this method has is it allows the user to select a range (e.g. 10-15) with a single click and drag motion. However without knowing more about the requirement I cannot say for sure if this is a common action, it might actually be more common to select many non-consecutive ages, instead of a range.

Comment: I like this. Saves space, could look nice, probably easier to implement and easier to use on a mobile than marvin's suggestion. An image would help translate your answer though.

Comment: @bluntfakie Sorry missed the dragging part :) Would be easier to make than Marvin's bar probably... :

Comment: Since it's for touch interfaces, I think this would work really well. I'd present it mainly as checkboxes, so that the user can just tap each if he doesn't get the painting metaphor, but provide a subtle hint for the power users.