# Relational query (few parameters selector) more user friendly

Tags: gui-design, multi-selection

I am working on GUI of one website which is selecting data from database.

User can enter one or two values if wants output above/equal/lessequal and less etc. or/and certain thresholds.

Current idea is like this:

[image]

nowadays I can use drag and drop, tool-tips etc. to apply it to certain select.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

What about a multiple-draggable slider? Here is [an example](http://blog.153.io/Elessar/) another user, [Martin](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/51566/marvin), provided in [another thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79682/selecting-age-between-6-and-18)

Your users may prefer keyboard input, so you might use this in conjunction with numerical input boxes.